# How to change Ng Bootstrap Datepicker Month and Days order

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using Ng Bootstrap datepicker calendar:

```
<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next"></ngb-datepicker>
```

The way the months are in the dropdown here are : Jan, Feb, Mar,...and so on.
And the week days are ordered starting Mon, Tue..

How do i change this name formatting ?
I need the months to display : January, February, March, April..
And the week days to start Sunday and only have first letter of the month

S M T W T F S

How do I change this without going into the node modules and changing it there?

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angular 4, 
For months do this in component.ts
     `displayMonths = 1; and navigation = 'arrows';`
And in html do this 
`[displayMonths]="displayMonths" and [navigation] = "navigation"`